# Trocar o namespace automaticamente ao mudar o arquivo de pasta

Tags: c#, namespace

Preciso reestruturar as pastas de um projeto, só que são muitos arquivos e os seus respectivos namespaces precisam ser alterados.

Existe algum modo de alterar o namespace automaticamente ao mover um arquivo .cs de uma pasta para outra?

Comment: Se utilizar o R# pode mudar os arquivos de pasta e no final utilizar a opção de ajustar os namespaces (seleccione os ficheiros, botão direito sobre os ficheiros, Refactor -> Adjust namespaces (atalho: Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R)).

Comment: Você pode instalar o ReSharper?

Comment: Omni e Cigano, eu utilizo o VS2013 Express. Tentei instalar ele mas não consegui por conta da versão.

Comment: @FilipeOliveira poderia tentar instalar o [CodeRush](https://www.devexpress.com/Home/try.xml) (não tenho a certeza que funcione no Express).

Comment: @Omni, o CodeRush também não funciona na no Express.

Comment: @FilipeOliveira a resposta do [Sunstreaker](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17730/8113) é capaz de o ajudar. Tenha só em atenção o comentário que fiz nessa resposta (evita dores de cabeça e acelera o processo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um modo para fazer isso no Visual Studio sem **auxilio externo** é fazer um simples *localizar e substituir*, pressione as teclas <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, vai abrir a janela mostrada abaixo, agora basta fazer a substituição do *namespace*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: efectivamente, à falta de auxilio externo é o melhor que se pode fazer. Apesar de ser melhor mudar o `Look in` para um escopo mais restrito (por exemplo abrir os ficheiros todos da pasta e fazer o `Find and Replace` nos ficheiros abertos.